# React-native component

Tags: javascript, react-native

I've written this react-native component which is giving me a bad feeling that it's not as good as my expectations.

I want to make it look cleaner with smart and less code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    View,
    Text,
    ScrollView,
    TextInput,
    TouchableOpacity,
    ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';

// Axios
const axios = require('axios').default;

// Toast
import Toast from 'react-native-simple-toast';

// Redux
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { authenticate } from '../redux/actions/Actions';

// AsyncStorage
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

// Style
import { style, textInput, button } from '../assets/Style';

class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            first_name: '',
            last_name: null,
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: '',
            password_confirmation: '',
            loading: false,
            errors: {}
        };
    }

    register() {
        const { first_name, last_name, username, email, password, password_confirmation } = this.state;
        this.setState({
            loading: true,
            errors: {}
        });

        axios.post('register', {
            first_name,
            last_name,
            username,
            email,
            password,
            password_confirmation
        }).then(({data}) => {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${data.token}`;
            AsyncStorage.setItem('token', data.token).then(() => {
                this.props.authenticate(true, {
                    user: data.user
                });
            });
        }).catch(error => {
            if (! error.response || (error.response && error.response.status !== 422)) {
                Toast.show('An error occurred.');
            } else {
                this.setState({
                    errors: error.response.data.errors
                });
            }
        }).finally(() => {
            this.setState({ loading: false });
        });
    }

    getMessages(field) {
        const { errors } = this.state;

        if (! errors[field])
            return <></>;

        return (
            <>{ errors[field].map((item, index) => <Text style={ style.inlineDangerMessage } key={index}>{item}</Text>) }</>
        );
    }


    render() {
        const { loading, errors } = this.state;
        const opacity = loading ? 0.5 : 1;
        const disabled = loading ? true : false;
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={ style.safeArea }>
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={ [style.flexCenter] }>
                    <View style={{ width: '60%' }}>
                        <TextInput style={ [textInput.default, (errors.first_name && style.isInvalidBottomBorder)] } placeholder="First name" defaultValue="" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ first_name: text })} />
                        { this.getMessages('first_name') }

                        <TextInput style={ [textInput.default, (errors.last_name && style.isInvalidBottomBorder), { marginTop: 10 }] } placeholder="Last name" defaultValue="" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ last_name: text })} />
                        { this.getMessages('last_name') }

                        <TextInput style={ [textInput.default, (errors.username && style.isInvalidBottomBorder), { marginTop: 10 }] } placeholder="Username" defaultValue="" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ username: text })} />
                        { this.getMessages('username') }

                        <TextInput style={ [textInput.default, (errors.email && style.isInvalidBottomBorder), { marginTop: 10 }] } placeholder="Email" defaultValue="" onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ email: text })} />
                        { this.getMessages('email') }

                        <TextInput style={ [textInput.default, (errors.password && style.isInvalidBottomBorder), { marginTop: 10 }] } placeholder="Password" defaultValue="" secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password: text })} />
                        { this.getMessages('password') }

                        <TextInput style={ [textInput.default, (errors.password_confirmation && style.isInvalidBottomBorder), { marginTop: 10 }] } placeholder="Password confirmation" defaultValue="" secureTextEntry={true} onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ password_confirmation: text })} />
                        { this.getMessages('password_confirmation') }

                        <TouchableOpacity style={ [button.primary, style.flexCenter, {
                            marginTop: 10,
                            height: 40,
                            opacity
                        }] } onPress={() => this.register()} disabled={disabled}>
                            { ! loading ?
                                <Text style={ [style.vazirBold, style.textCenter, { color: '#fff' }] }>Register</Text> : 
                                <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="#fff" />
                            }
                        </TouchableOpacity>

                        <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginTop: 15 }} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()} disabled={loading}>
                            <Text style={ [button.link, style.textCenter] }>I already have an account!</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const { redux } = state
    return { redux }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => (
    bindActionCreators({
        authenticate,
    }, dispatch)
);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Register);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to use `if` and `<></>` for conditional-rendering:

   ```
     getMessages(field) {
       const { errors } = this.state;
       return (
         errors[field] && errors[field].map((item, index) => (
           <Text style={style.inlineDangerMessage} key={index}>
             {item}
           </Text>
         ))
       )
     }
   ```
2. You can reuse the `TextInput` since there are many of them:

   - build an array of what you need

     ```
     const field = [
       { id: "1", attr: "first_name", placeholder: "First name" },
       { id: "2", attr: "last_name", placeholder: "Last name" }
       // ...
     ];
     ```
   - write common function

     ```
       styleFunction = attrName => {
         const { errors } = this.state;
         return [textInput.default, errors[attrName] && style.isInvalidBottomBorder];
       };
     ```
   - and map the repeated components

     ```
     {field.map(item => (
       <>
         <TextInput
           style={this.styleFunction(item.attr)}
           placeholder={item.placeholder}
           defaultValue=""
           onChangeText={text => this.setState({ [item.attr]: text })}
         />
         {this.getMessages(item.attr)}
       </>
     ))}
     ```

---

I'm sure there are other places where can be improved. As far as my immediate view, that's what I have got.

All the code here:

[image: Edit objective-cdn-rhh9y]

Comment: I just want to add one more thing create router classes for webservices rather than using axios everytime.